# How to achieve Qt "Blocking Auto Connection"

Tags: multithreading, qt

The different [Qt method invocation and signal-slot connection types](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) have these alternatives:

- *Direct connection*: Call method in current thread, obviously blocking.
- *Queued connection*: Call method from event loop of receiver, never blocking.
- *Auto connection*: Call method in target object's thread, blocking if current, otherwise queuing and not blocking.
- *Blocking queued connection*: Call method in target object's thread, blocking if not current thread, otherwise *deadlocking*.

However, **I have need for something like "Blocking Auto Connection"**, which would act as direct connection if target object lives in same thread, blocking queued connection otherwise.

**How?**

---

For reference, the current solution appears to boil down to this... Which obviously is not a good way to do this. Fortunately it is in a location where it does not really matter, but still... Anyway, no need to comment about that, this is *not* a code review question :-)

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(target, "method", Qt::AutoConnection, ...);
// If same thread, method call is already done here and sleep is skipped
while(!target->isDone()) sleep(1);
```

Comment: If you can make the slot cooperate, how about a `QSemaphore` with an auto connection type? You can release it in the slot, and acquire it after emitting the signal / metainvoking the slot.

Comment: That sounds like it would work, yeah!

Comment: file a bug report and request it...

Comment: @ratchetfreak or, I can leave the idea out here, and then if there is another person who might need this, they might file a report... ;) Either way, it's not going to help with the particular project, which motivated this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested answer from OP:

Helper method:

```
Qt::ConnectionType autoBlockingConnection(const QObject *target) {
    return QThread::getCurrentThread() == target->thread()
        ? Qt::DirectConnection
        : Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection;
}
```

Usage:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(target, "method", autoBlockingConnection(target), ...);
```

Potential problem with this is, it might not work if current thread has not been created by Qt.

A note: it's not possible to use QThread::getCurrentThreadID(), because there's no corresponding non-static method, to get the thread id for `target`.

General warnings: Same care must be taken with inter-thread invocations, same as with standard `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`. For example, if the target method does same kind of method invocation (or signal) *back* to calling thread (which has event loop blocked), then both threads will deadlock.

Comment: QThread::getCurrentThread() doesn't exist for me.
QThread::currentThread() appears to do the trick.